# increase the length of title in search result in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results, display-template

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and sharepoint 2013 search.

when i search for certain items i get results, but the title of certain items shows with a trailing dots after showing some characters of the title and truncating the rest.

For example: let the title be "This is a sample title just for testing" and in the search result the title is shown as "This is a sample title just....". So aftre displaying some part of the title it is showing ... I need to hover over the item to see the full title.Is there any option to show the full title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried as told by Sane.Amit. But still i am getting the same result.

Because it is already trimmed in the display template.

So i updated the display template Item_CommonItem_Body.

I replaced the below portion

```
var titleHtml = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" id="{1}" href="{2}" class="ms-srch-item-link" title="{3}" onfocus="{4}" {5}>{6}</a>',
                                          $htmlEncode(clickType), $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.titleLink), $urlHtmlEncode(url), $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title), 
                                          showHoverPanelCallback, appAttribs, Srch.U.trimTitle(title, maxTitleLengthInChars, termsToUse));
```

with the below code

```
var titleHtml = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" id="{1}" href="{2}" class="ms-srch-item-link" title="{3}" onfocus="{4}" {5}>{3}</a>',
                                          $htmlEncode(clickType), $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.titleLink), $urlHtmlEncode(url), $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title), 
                                          showHoverPanelCallback, appAttribs, Srch.U.trimTitle(title, maxTitleLengthInChars, termsToUse));
```

This brought the full title but in single line.

Now i changed the CSS with the below change:

```
.ms-srch-ellipsis
{
/*white-space:nowrap;*/
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Now it worked nicely as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The title of each search result is governed by the `css` associated with `.ms-srch-ellipsis` class.

```
.ms-srch-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Due to the `text-overflow` property being set to `ellipsis` you are seeing the title followed by a few dots. I think it is better to keep it this way around. And in case you wish to change it, you can remove `ellipsis` attribute and also you can add `width` attribute for this class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `$htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title)` which shows original title, instead of highlighted title. However with this approach your titles won’t be highlighted anymore. You probably need to add some extra logic to keep highlighted functionality.